# How to stop cubeslider slideshow on mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I am using a Cube Slider 3d plugin for a slideshow and I have it starting on 'mouseenter' using jQuery, which works fine.  I want it to stop on 'mouseleave' and cannot get it to work.  Been unable to find anything to guide me in the right direction.  Please see the code below.  It is the code I use to start.  As you can see, there is an autoplay option, which I set to 'true'.  Logic would tell me to set the value to false on mouseleave, but that does not work and seems a bit redundant to use cubeslider() again.  I have also tried jQuery method stop() and thought about trying to use setInterval() and clearInterval() with it somehow.  With using a jQuery plugin it doesn't seem like much additional jQuery/JavaScript would be needed.  I could be wrong as I've been neglecting jQuery/JavaScript for another focus and probably need a refresher on many JavaScript concepts.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

```
$('#cubeSlide').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#cubeSlide').cubeslider({
        cubesNum: {rows:1, cols:1},
        orientation: 'h',
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayInterval: 500,
        perspective: 1200,
        mode3d: 'auto',
        arrows: false,
        navigation: false,
        addShadow: false,
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have a demo possibly with all the code ?

Comment: @ZachPerkitny, I currently do not have a demo.  I can work on getting a demo up.  It doesn't seem like it should be this difficult to get it to work, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It doesn't seem to override the original settings.